# Switching between two select drop down in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, select, drop-down-menu

I'm having two drop down list .with JSON data

```
<select class="form control" ng-model="fruitsName" ng-options="r.id as r.name for r in fruits">
<option value="">--Select---</option></select>

$scope.fruits = [{'id': 'AL', 'name': 'Apple'},{'id': 'FL', 'name': 'Orange'},{'id': 'CA', 'name': Mango'},{'id': 'DE', 'name': 'PineApple'}];

 <select class="form control" ng-model="sellerName" ng-options="r.id as r.name for r in seller">
<option value=""></option></select>

$scope.seller = [{'id': 'AL', 'name': 'John'},{'id': 'FL', 'name': 'Miller'},{'id': 'CA', 'name': 'Jack'},{'id': 'DE', 'name': 'Smith'}];
```

My requirement:If I select an Item in first drop down then second select dropdown should be autofilled with its first item,and vice versa.

Any help will be really apreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the first `ng-options` as below

```
<select class="form control" ng-model="fruitsName" ng-options="r as r.name for r in fruits" ng-change="selectSecond()">
<option value="">--Select---</option>
```

inside the controller

```
 $scope.selectSecond = function(obj) {
     var selected = $scope.fruitsName;
     var index = $scope.fruits.indexOf(selected);
     $scope.selectedFroutIndex = index;

     $scope.sellerName = $scope.seller[$scope.selectedFroutIndex].id;    
}
```

here is the Demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YA40nLNdFnUrwoOcZKKm?p=preview)

---

if you are not interested in changing the `ng-options`

```
 <select class="form control" ng-model="fruitsName" ng-options="r.id as r.name for r in fruits" ng-change="selectSecond()">
     <option value="">--Select---</option>
 </select>
```

then your controller should be like

```
$scope.selectSecond = function() {
    var selected = $scope.fruitsName;
    var index = -1;
    angular.forEach($scope.fruits , function(value, key) {
      if(value.id === selected) {
        index = key;
       return;
      }
    })
    $scope.selectedFroutIndex = index;
    $scope.sellerName = $scope.seller[$scope.selectedFroutIndex].id;
}
```

here is the Demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2DT2oUUMTcSh8K3JiufD?p=preview)

---

if you need the vice versa do the same

here is the Demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6pbzpoSaCk2z5sB6atSH?p=preview)